# Running command from Git bash throws error

Tags: cypress, git-bash

Unable to run the below command from Git bash. I am getting below error;
`$ CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com/book/ npx cypress open`

Folder path:  `C:/Users/Some Name1/project`

**Error:**

`C:\Users\Some Name1/' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Git version:
git version 2.28.0.windows.1
Os: Windows10

Comment: It works fine (Cypress opens with `baseUrl:"https://someurl.com/book/"`). Does your real path have a space? Get rid of it .

Comment: Yes my test folder called `project` lies under the following path  `C:/Users/Some Name1` and `Some Name1` folder has space in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if upgrading to the latest [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.31) does improve the situation.

If not, as commented, try and substitute your current path (with space) by a drive letter, [using `subst`](https://ss64.com/nt/subst.html), starting with a regular CMD:

```
subst X "C:\User\Some Name"
bash
cd /X/project
CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://someurl.com/book/ npx cypress open
```

Comment: Thank you where do we give the `subst X "C:\User\Some Name"` details

Comment: @soccerway "where do we give"? in a CMD, in order to replace your path with space by a drive letter.